# Найти строки содержащие слово `bot` кроме `googlebot`

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пожалуйста регулярку которая найдет строки которые содержат слово `bot` но строки содержащие `googlebot` чтобы пропускала

Answer (score 4):

Ищем `bot`, с отрицанием впередистоящего `google`:

```
(?<!google)bot
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UdkC6m/1)